# GitLab CI invalid argument on job for Docker build

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

So I'm trying to setup my Gitlab CI to trigger a job on `git push` to build and deploy my Docker. This is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I'm using based on an example from Gitlab docs (Elixir yml).

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  before_script:
    - docker build -f Dockerfile.build -t ci-project-build-$CI_PROJECT_ID:$CI_BUILD_REF .
    - docker create
      -v /build/deps 
      -v /build/_build
      -v /build/rel
      -v /root/.cache/aceapp/
      --name build_data_$CI_PROJECT_ID_$CI_BUILD_REF busybox /bin/true
  tags:
    - docker
  stage: build
  script: 
    - docker run --volumes-from build_data_$CI_PROJECT_ID_$CI_BUILD_REF --rm -t ci-project-build-$CI_PROJECT_ID:$CI_BUILD_REF
```

The output when pushing to GitLab instance is this:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.7.2 (b5e03c94)
on my.host.rhel.runner 8f724ea7
Using Shell executor...
Running on my.host.local...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 14351c4 Merge branch 'Development' into 'master'
From https://my.host.example/zalmosc/ace-app
   14351c4..9fa2d43  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 9fa2d435 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ # Auto DevOps variables and functions # collapsed multi-line command
$ setup_docker
$ build
Logging to GitLab Container Registry with CI credentials...
Login Succeeded

Building Dockerfile-based application...
invalid argument "/master:9fa2d4358e6c426b882e2251aa5a49880013614b" for t: Error parsing reference: "/master:9fa2d4358e6c426b882e2251aa5a49880013614b" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I understand the docker tag is not valid (is the `before_script:` really triggered based on the name?), and I'm looking for help regarding a) a solution b) how I can learn more about the requirements for a pipeline that builds docker based on default settings. Do I need to tag my docker image locally and then somehow add this to my git commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is `-t` is to tag your Docker image. See the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

The tag should be formated like `name:version`, and you giving it `/master:9fa2d4358e6c426b882e2251aa5a49880013614b` which is not a valid tag. You could try to delete the `/` before `master`

Comment: So the default build script for Docker images in Gitlab CI isn't doing a correct `-t` implementation? 

Thanks, I'll have a further look.

Comment: It does. It is not related to Docker, but to the arguments you pass in gitlab.ci.yml to your Docker command. These are wrong. Feel free to ask more questions, or to accept my answer so that the other are also helped :)

Comment: Most likely in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Comment: @Mornor where to edit it for gitlab's "auto devops" script?

Answer (score 1):

Your tag cannot begin with '/':

```
$ docker build -f Dockerfile.build -t /master:9fa2d4358e6c426b882e2251aa5a49880013614b .
invalid argument "/master:9fa2d4358e6c426b882e2251aa5a49880013614b" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.

# remove '/'
$ docker build -f Dockerfile.build -t master:9fa2d4358e6c426b882e2251aa5a49880013614b .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
---> 14f60031763d
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the built in registry, you might have to set the CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE value to something. It seems that if you don't se this it gets set to /master and causes this error. you can set this in the CI setting page, or when making a new pipeline. e.g CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE gitlab.com/user/project